# Create rounded cached image in Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I want to create a circle image where the image is fetched from the network and is also cached in Flutter.

Here is a code I found for a round image fetched from the network but the image not being cached.

```
new Container(
    width:80.0,
    height: 80.0,
    decoration: new BoxDecoration(
    shape: BoxShape.circle,
        image: new DecorationImage(
            image: new NetworkImage('https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/945853318273761280/0U40alJG_400x400.jpg'),
        ),
    ),
),
```

Now I found a widget for fetching, caching and presenting a image from the network

```
new CachedNetworkImage(imageUrl: 'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/945853318273761280/0U40alJG_400x400.jpg')
```

But when I replace the NetworkImage widget with this CachedNetworkImage, it gives me an error saying the NetworkImage is not type image.

How can I achieve a round image that can be cached?

Edited:
I tried this as suggested in the answer, but still got the same error: The argument type 'CachedNetworkImage' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'DecorationImage'.

```
              decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                image: new CachedNetworkImage(image: 
                      'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/945853318273761280/0U40alJG_400x400.jpg'),
              ),
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

ClipOval widget is used to clip child widget into round shapes.

```
ClipOval(
  child: CachedNetworkImage(imageUrl: "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/945853318273761280/0U40alJG_400x400.jpg",
   width: 80.0,
   height: 80.0,
  ),
)
```

Comment: Instead of using ClipRRect (which is basically used for rounded corners rectangle), you should probably be using ClipOval

Comment: This does not work with rectangular images even with `fit: BoxFit.cover`

Comment: @aytunch I would be happy to see your code if you could post it to stack overflow

Comment: How is this the accepted answer! ClipOval does not look like a perfect circle!

Comment: @SamersSalib When you have the width and height equal to each other, it will.

Comment: Tried this, it initially shows the square image as soon as fetched from URL, then changes to circle (if width and height are same), that looks really bad from UI perspective.

Comment: @VipiNNegi If what you are describing is happening, it is a probably a bug. May I see your code?

Comment: sure, how do I share?

Comment: @VipiNNegi You can maybe create a codepen and share the URL here?

Comment: https://codepen.io/vipinnegi90/pen/PoZLNMv  there you go :) With the below answer, wrapping CachedNetworkImageProvider with CircleAvatar worked just great.

Answer (score 115):

The [CachedNetworkImage](https://github.com/renefloor/flutter_cached_network_image/blob/master/lib/src/cached_image_widget.dart) has a builder (`ImageWidgetBuilder`) to further customize the display of the image.
Try it this way:

```
CachedNetworkImage(
  imageUrl: 'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/945853318273761280/0U40alJG_400x400.jpg',
  imageBuilder: (context, imageProvider) => Container(
    width: 80.0,
    height: 80.0,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      shape: BoxShape.circle,
      image: DecorationImage(
        image: imageProvider, fit: BoxFit.cover),
    ),
  ),
  placeholder: (context, url) => CircularProgressIndicator(),
  errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Icon(Icons.error),
),
```

`placeholder` and `errorWidget` are widgets, which means you can put any widget in there and customize them as you wish.

Comment: This solution will **only work with a square picture**, as otherwise, the CircularProgressIndicator will have the same ratio as the picture.

Comment: error widget will be not circled

Answer (score 38):

*[`DecorationImage`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/painting/DecorationImage-class.html)* takes an [`ImageProvider`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/painting/ImageProvider-class.html) and not a ***widget***.

There are *two ways* to solve this problem:

The [`cached_image_network`](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/cached_network_image) provides a `class` that `extends` `ImageProvider`, i.e. ***`CachedNetworkImageProvider`***:

```
Container(
  width: 80.0,
  height: 80.0,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    shape: BoxShape.circle,
    image: DecorationImage(
      image: CachedNetworkImageProvider('https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/945853318273761280/0U40alJG_400x400.jpg'),
    ),
  ),
)
```

You could also just omit the *`DecorationImage`* widget because the `BoxDecoration` *will work* on **any** widget:

```
Container(
  width: 80.0,
  height: 80.0,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    shape: BoxShape.circle,
  ),
  child: CachedNetworkImage('https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/945853318273761280/0U40alJG_400x400.jpg'),
)
```

In the latter example, I am using the regular ***[`CachedNetworkImage`](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/cached_network_image)***, which will return a *widget*.

Comment: Thank you for you answer! I tried both of your answer; the first one worked, but the latter example did not work... Still getting the same error: The argument type 'CachedNetworkImage' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'DecorationImage'.

Comment: @creativecreatormaybenot I actually did copy it the way you told me to do so as in the edit, but still did not work.

Comment: @dshukertjr Yes, screw me, I messed that up. You need to pass the `CachedNetworkImage` as the `child` to the `Container`. I *updated* that in the answer.

Comment: @creativecreatormaybenot Thanks! Everything works now!

Comment: @dshukertjr  can we use LRU cached in this example

Comment: This does not work with rectangular images. even with `fit: BoxFit.cover`

Answer (score 12):

The combination of `CircleAvatar` and `CachedNetworkImageProvider` solves your problem.
Here is an example:

```dart
CircleAvatar(
  backgroundImage: CachedNetworkImageProvider(
  'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/945853318273761280/0U40alJG_400x400.jpg',
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 7):

in my case this save my time , mybe you too.

```dart
CachedNetworkImage(
  imageUrl: url,
  errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Text("error"),
  imageBuilder: (context, imageProvider) => CircleAvatar(
    radius: 50,
    backgroundImage: imageProvider,
   ),
  );
```

Answer (score 2):

### General solution for any dimension

A Solution for pictures with any dimension and corner radius:

```dart
Container(
   width: 100,
   height: 125,
   decoration: BoxDecoration(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(34.0),
      color: Colors.grey,
   ),
   child: ClipRRect(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(34.0),
      child: CachedNetworkImage(
         imageUrl: "url",
         fit: BoxFit.cover,
         placeholder: (context, url) => Center(
            child: SizedBox(
               width: 40.0,
               height: 40.0,
               child: new CircularProgressIndicator(),
            ),
         ),
         errorWidget: (context, url, error) => new Icon(Icons.error),
      ),
   ),
),
```

Comment: This is the perfect answer. Solves all the issues.

Answer (score 0):

It will work by using a `Container` and `ClipRRect`. Here is an example:

```
Container(
  width: 160,
  height: 160,
    child: ClipRRect(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(80),
      child: CachedNetworkImage(
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
        imageUrl: '[YOUR URL]',
        errorWidget: (
          context,
          url,
          error,
        ) =>
          const Icon(Icons.error),
        progressIndicatorBuilder: (
          context,
          url,
          downloadProgress,
        ) =>
          Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(
              value: downloadProgress.progress),
            ),
          )
      ),
    ),
```

The `width` and `height` of your `Container` widget are important and both should be the same.

I hope that will be useful for others ;-)